# How to pass mouse_pos values to draw ellipse to develop paint app in kivy in python?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to develop a paint app which creates ellipse or circle as the mouse is moved on the canvas

Comment: Please add more details including what you have already tried and what problems you are having.

Answer (score 0):

There is great examples on how to make drawing apps on kivy's website.
Take a look at it [Drawing app in kivy](https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/firstwidget.html)

An example from the site.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 1, 0)
            d = 30.
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]


class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyPaintWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Comment: This program uses mouse click and drag. I would like to know how the values obtained from mouse_pos function in kivy can be used to draw ellipse and create a running trail as mouse moves on the canvas.